# Writing to linux tty (/dev/) files in c#

Tags: c#, linux, file, mono, tty

I need my program to execute a command that in Bash would look like this: 
"echo P1-12=175 > /dev/servoblaster". How do I do this in Mono/C# on Linux? I wrote the following class:

```
public static class ServoBlasterPWM
{
    private static FileStream devFile;

    public static bool IsRunning
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static bool Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            devFile = File.Open("/dev/servoblaster", FileMode.Open);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("Error while setting up port for Servo Blaster: " + e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        Log.Success("ServoBlaster is set up.");
        IsRunning = true;

        return true;
    }

    public static void SetPWMOutput(int pin, int valueSteps)
    {
        //byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("P1-" + pin.ToString() + "=" + valueSteps.ToString());

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("P1-12=175");
        devFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        devFile.Flush();

        Console.WriteLine("Wrote to file");
    }

    public static void Shutdown()
    {
        devFile.Close();
        IsRunning = false;

        Log.Info("Servo Blaster has been shut down.");
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work. I also tried StreamWriter instead of FileStream, but it crashed with an exception saying that the stream does not support seeking. I have no idea how to do this. Please help.

Comment: See the answer here for another way with ServoBaster: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10495/how-to-call-servoblaster-from-c-mono

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the string to array code by:

```
byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("P1-12=175") ;
```

or:

```
byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes("P1-12=175") ;
```